# PHP variable and array combinations

Tags: php, mysql

```
$nopa = "Shotgun";
$weapon1        = array("Ingen","Shotgun","Glock 17","Revolver","AK 47","Barrett M82");
```

How can i do so this code will output a yes if the $weapon is equal to $nopa, else it would output a no. Any ideas?

Comment: you might want to try in_array function for this.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `in_array` from PHP documentation stated here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Answer (score 2):

Check the PHP function "in_array"

http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

```
if ( in_array($stringVar, $arrayVar) ) {
  //do something
}
```

Careful about case, however.

> If needle is a string, the comparison is done in a case-sensitive
>   manner.

Answer (score 0):

check out the built-in in_array function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Answer (score 0):

this is what You want:

```
<?
$nopa = "Shotgun";
$weapon1        = array("Ingen","Shotgun","Glock 17","Revolver","AK 47","Barrett M82");
if (in_array($nopa,$weapon1)){
    echo 'YES';
} else {
    echo 'NO';
}
?>
```

[WORKING CODE](http://codepad.org/9ElyPlbM)